SQL Error [16777217]: Query failed (#20240710_084433_00075_u2prc): java.io.IOException: Start token not found where expected
I'm trying to create table in trino using hive-connector and minio as storage layer to query logs present in json array of objects file by the following command:
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS minio.camsLogs.dev1 (
    "date" timestamp,
    "log_level" VARCHAR,
    "message" VARCHAR,
    "timestamp" timestamp,
    "class" VARCHAR
)
WITH (
external_location = 's3a://test-bucket/',
format = 'JSON'
);

The sample logs file looks like this:Sample JSON file
But upon trying to view the table I get the following error: SQL Error [16777217]: Query failed (#20240710_084433_00075_u2prc): java.io.IOException: Start token not found where expected.
I'm trying to store logs in minio in json format with each json file containing array of objects where each object has keys corresponding to a log and then trying to query on the logs data using trino-hive connector and Dbeaver.

Did you find any solution?
